# How to create half circular-window hole on the wall without resulting ngon?

Tags: modeling

how to create half circular-window hole, I think it called arched window? I only know using knife project, but it will make ngon, and I must cut it one by one into tris/quad.

so, do you know another way to window hole for arched window without resulting ngon?
[image]

Comment: The answer below didn't address the question asked, and the GIFs he uploaded are causing major problems trying to load. The solution to your problem is to subdivide the face several times, then remove the faces where the arch should be. Use the Circle tool in the LoopTools addon to round out the edges of the opening, and adjust them to suit your needs.

Answer (score 5):

In answer to the question:

- Select the face that you want to put an arch opening in
- Subdivide enough times to suit your needs:

[image]

- Select the edges that surround the area where your arch opening will be:

[image]

- Select the Circle tool from the LoopTools addon (available in User Preferences if not already installed). This will move the selected edges into a circular shape:

[image]

- At this point, you can either delete the bottom half of the original face and rebuild the mesh for the lower part of your door opening, or you can realign the vertices that will form the door opening by copy/pasting the appropriate transform values to line them up on the z axis. To do this, just place the mouse cursor over the appropriate transform value and press Ctrl-C:

[image]

- Individually select each vertex below the one you just copied the value from, and paste the value into the same transform field by just placing the mouse over it and pressing Ctrl-V. You should end up with something like this:

[image]

- Now you can delete the faces that form the arched doorway.

Answer (score 0):

## Preparation

The best method to create a nice fitting window (glass) is with a copy of the inner loop of your window.

Select the window, tab into Edit Mode, then select the inner loop, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the vertices and then <kbd>P</kbd> to create a new object from the duplicated vertices.

Tab into Object Mode, select the new mesh and tab into Edit Mode again.

[image: Create Window Loop]

## Create Window

Now we are going to create the faces for the window. Start at the top and select either 4 vertices or - if you have a vertex in the center - select 5 vertices. Hit <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face, then proceed until everything is filled.

[image: create faces]

If your topmost face is an ngon, go to edge select, select all horizontal edges and subdivide them once. Then, switch to face select mode, select the upper face, hit <kbd>X</kbd> and select "Only Faces".

Switch to vertex select mode, and create two faces out of four vertices. Hit <kbd>W</kbd> and select "Remove Doubles", in case there are leftovers.

[image: replace ngon]

There you go, a perfectly fitting window for your frame, completely made out of quads.

## Creating the Window Cavity

Select your window frame, tab into Edit Mode, select the outer loop that connects to the wall. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate it, then hit <kbd>P</kbd> - "Selection" to create a new object.

[image: prepare cavity]

Tab into Object Mode, select your Window and hide it. Then select your House, tab into Edit Mode and delete the face that should have the cavity.

Tab into Object Mode, select the window loop, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-select the house and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join both objects.

Tab into Edit Mode and select the two lowest vertices from the window arc and the vertex in the corner at the same side of the house. Hit <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face (triangle). Proceed until you have both sides of the arc covered, then close the rest of the gaps.

[image: create cavity]

When you are done you should have a pattern similar to this:

[image]

Now you have quads and triangles without the need of adding loopcuts to the rest of your house.

Comment: Thank, but its not the case, I already have 1 complete window(include frame and leaf). I need create hole on the wall with same shape with my window because I will put my window in the wall, my window is thin that's why I need create clean looking hole in the wall,

Comment: And this is *exactly* why you should have written about the "hole in the wall" when you mean the hole in the wall. ;-) It's exactly the same method, only the other way round. I'll update my explanation, as soon as I have time...

Comment: Use Mirror modifier to minimize amount of work done; also `Alt` is useful for selecting boundary loops to be filled. Surrounding opened hole for the window with an edge loop could be better approach because of avoiding shading artifacts.

Comment: @MrZak, applying a mirror modifiert for five minutes of work doesn't sound very reasonable. And there is no shading on the wall either. This method is the cleanest and fastest without adding too many loopcuts around the whole building.

Comment: I didn't mean to apply Mirror mod rather than only shrtening gifs which are a bit hard to watch. Fastest way - maybe. Cleanest ? A corner vertex with 8 shared edges ? Well, quite sirprising.

Comment: @MrZak - I never had any shading problems in any game engine in the last past +10 years when using that method on a flat surface. But yeah, so BlenderSE is all about sharing. If you have a better idea, I'm always willing to learn something new and there's always room for another answer.

Comment: Overall surrounding loop was mentioned as a room for imrpovement house geometry - no house is flat and with perfectly square angles. However there shouldn't be answer about that - yours covers flat surfaces.