# How can i round some vertex on a flat object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I created this object but i want to make it round at the top like the screenshot. How can i make it? I know that bevel is one option but i am not sure how to use it in this object since it's flat.

[image: screenshot 1]

Update: I created those cuts, how can i make them into a round shape now?

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create half circular-window hole on the wall without resulting ngon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61327/how-to-create-half-circular-window-hole-on-the-wall-without-resulting-ngon)

Answer (score 0):

You could add additional edge loops like this:

[image]

Be aware that the top face is a ngon, which you may want to convert into quads.